# Big commerce multi language error of translation stencil theme

Tags: html, json, bigcommerce, stencils

I am using stencil theme on my bigcommerce store, the theme URL is this

https://themeforest.net/item/laparis-simple-creative-responsive-bigcommerce-theme-stencil-based/19715248

And here is my store URL:  https://salondlamody.com/

I have to translate whole the store to change variable values in en.json file according to my language, and its working fine. but when I reached checkout page the translation not working.

After study this URL: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/multi-language-checkout

I have to download optimize_checkout files and translate whole the variable values I have added the code to my en.json file.

**But it's still not working ...............!**

Below is the code of my optimization check out which one I am using my en.json file

```
    "optimized_checkout": {
        "address": {
            "address_line_1_label": "Ulica i numer domu / mieszkania",
            "address_line_1_required_error": "Uzupełnij pierwszą linię adresu",
            "address_line_2_label": "Adres c.d.",
            "address_line_2_required_error": "Uzupełnij pierwszą linię adresu",
            "address_not_recognized_heading": "Nie rozpoznaliśmy Twojego adresu. Prosze sprawdź dane",
            "city_label": "Miasto",
            "city_required_error": "Podanie Miasta jest wymagane.",
            "company_name_label": "Firma",
            "company_name_required_error": "Podanie firmy jest wymagane.",
            "confirm_address_action": "Kontynuuj",
            "confirm_address_text": "Nie możemy znaleźć powiązania z podanym adresem. Proszę potwierdzić adres.",
            "country_label": "Kraj",
            "country_required_error": "Podanie kraju jest wymagane",
            "edit_address_action": "Edytuj adres",
            "enter_address_action": "Podaj nowy adres",
            "first_name_label": "Imię",
            "first_name_required_error": "Podanie imienia jest wymagane",
            "last_name_label": "Nazwisko",
            "last_name_required_error": "Podanie nazwiska jest wymagane",
            "phone_number_label": "Numer teleonu",
            "phone_number_required_error": "Podanie numeru teleonu jest wymagane",
            "postal_code_label": "Kod pocztowy",
            "postal_code_required_error": "Podanie kodu pocztowego jest wymagane",
            "select_country_action": "Wybierz kraj",
            "select_state_action": "Wybierz województwo",
            "state_label": "Województwo/Stan",
            "state_required_error": "Województwo jest wymagane."
        },
        "billing": {
            "billing_address_heading": "Adres rozliczeniowy",
            "billing_heading": "Faktura",
            "save_billing_address_error": "Wystąpił błąd podczas zapisywania adresu rozliczeniowego. Proszę spróbować ponownie.",
            "use_shipping_address_label": "Moje dane do aktury są takie same jak adres dostawy."
        },
        "cart": {
            "based_on_currency_text": "Cena na podstawie {total} {code}",
            "cart_heading": "Podsumowanie zamówienia",
            "digital_item_text": "Produkty wirtualne",
            "discount_text": "Zniżka",
            "downloads_action": "Przejdź do pobierania",
            "edit_cart_action": "Edytuj koszyk",
            "estimated_total_text": "Szacowana suma",
            "free_text": "Darmowa",
            "gift_certificate_text": "Kod podarunkowy",
            "handling_text": "Obsługa",
            "item_count_text": "{count, plural, one{1 produkt} two {2 produkty} three{3 produkty} four{4 produkty} other{# produktów} }",
            "print_action": "Drukuj",
            "remove_action": "usuń",
            "see_all_action": "Zobacz wszystko",
            "see_less_action": "Zwiń",
            "shipping_text": "Dostawa",
            "show_details_action": "Zobacz szczegóły",
            "store_credit_text": "Złotówki z karty podarunkowej",
            "subtotal_text": "Podsuma",
            "taxes_text": "w tym VAT",
            "total_text": "Suma",
            "Congratulations!":"Gratulacje!"
        },
        "common": {
            "cancel_action": "Anuluj",
            "close_action": "Zamknij",
            "continue_action": "Kontynuuj",
            "edit_action": "Edytuj",
            "error_heading": "Coś poszło nie tak",
            "leave_warning": "Czy jesteś pewien, że chcesz wyjść? Możesz utracić wprowadzone dane.",
            "loading_text": "Ładowanie",
            "ok_action": "Ok",
            "optional_text": "Opcjonalnie",
            "unavailable_error": "Kasa jest chwilowo niedostępna. Proszę spróbowac później.",
            "unavailable_heading": "Kasa jest chwilowo niedostępna"
        },
        "customer": {
            "checkout_as_guest_text": "Zapłacić w kasie jako <strong>Gość</strong>? Będziesz mógł zapisać szczegóły zamówienia aby utworzyć konto później",
            "continue_as_guest_action": "Kontynnuj jako gość",
            "create_account_action": "Utwórz konto",
            "create_account_error": "Wystąpił błąd podczas tworzenia Twojego konta. Proszę spóbuj jeszcze raz.",
            "create_account_success": "Twoje konto zostało utowrzone!",
            "create_account_text": "Utwórz konto aby szybko składać zamówienia.",
            "create_account_to_continue_text": "Nie masz konta? <a href=\"/login.php?action=create_account\" target=\"_blank\">Utwórz konto</a> aby kontynuować.",
            "customer_heading": "Klient",
            "email_invalid_error": "Adres e-mail musi być aktualny",
            "email_label": "Adres e-mail",
            "email_required_error": "Adres e-mail jest wymagany",
            "forgot_password_action": "Zapomniałeś hasła?",
            "guest_customer_text": "Gość",
            "login_action": "Zarejestruj teraz",
            "login_text": "Posiadasz już konto?",
            "password_confirmation_error": "Hasła nie pasują",
            "password_confirmation_label": "Potwierdź hasło",
            "password_confirmation_required_error": "To pole jest wymagane.",
            "password_label": "Hasło",
            "password_letter_required_error": "Hasło musi zawierać literę",
            "password_minimum_character_label": "Rozróżniana jest wielkość liter",
            "password_number_required_error": "Hasło musi zawierać cyrę",
            "password_over_maximum_length_error": "Hasło jest za długie",
            "password_required_error": "Hasło jest wymagane",
            "password_under_minimum_length_error": "Hasło za krótkie",
            "returning_customer_text": "Jestem już klientem sklepu",
            "sign_in_action": "Zaloguj",
            "sign_in_error": "E-mail lub hasło nie pasują.",
            "sign_in_throttled_error": "Za dużo prób logowania, prosze zaczekać 10 sekund pomiedzy kolejnymi próbami logowania.",
            "sign_out_action": "Wyloguj",
            "sign_out_error": "Wystąpił błąd podczas wylogowywania. Prosze spróbuj jeszcze raz.",
            "subscribe_to_newsletter_text": "Tak, chcę otrzymywac najnowsze aktualizacje."

        },
        "payment": {
            "amazon_continue_action": "Kontynnuj przez Amazon",
            "amazon_name_text": "Amazon Pay",
            "credit_card_cvv_label": "CVV",
            "credit_card_expiration_invalid_error": "Data ważności karty muszi być aktualna oraz zawierac się w ormacie MM/RR",
            "credit_card_expiration_label": "Data ważności",
            "credit_card_expiration_required_error": "Data ważności jest wymagana",
            "credit_card_name_label": "Dane właściela",
            "credit_card_name_required_error": "Imię i nazwisko jest wymagane",
            "credit_card_cvv_invalid_error": "Kod CVV musi być ważny",
            "credit_card_cvv_required_error": "Kod CVV jest wymagany",
            "credit_card_cvv_help_text": "Dla kard VISA i Mastercard, kod CVV jest trzycyfową wartością zamieszczoną z tyłu karty.",
            "credit_card_number_invalid_error": "Karta płatnicza musi być ważna",
            "credit_card_number_label": "Numer karty płatniczej",
            "credit_card_number_required_error": "Numer karty płatniczej jest wymagany.",
            "klarna_name_text": "Klarna",
            "payment_cancelled": "Płatność została anulowana.",
            "payment_error": "Please try again. Wystąpił błąd podczas przetważania Twojej płatności. Proszę spróbować jeszcze raz.",
            "payment_heading": "Płatność",
            "payment_method_disabled_error": "Wybrana metoda płatności nie jest dłużej dostępna. Kliknij OK aby zobaczyć aktualnie dostępne metody płatności.",
            "payment_method_error": "Wiadomośc od agenta płatności: {message}",
            "payment_method_invalid_error": "Wystąpił problem podczas przetwarzania Twojej płatności w sklepie. Skontaktuj się ze sprzedawcą lub wybierz inną metodę płatności.",
            "payment_method_label": "Metoda Płatności",
            "payment_method_unavailable_error": "Ten dostawca płatności jest czasowo niedostępny. Prosze spróbowac później",
            "payment_not_required_text": "Ta płatność nie jest dostępna dla tego zamówienia.",
            "paypal_continue_action": "Kontynuuj przez PayPal",
            "paypal_description_text": "Pay zapłać przez konto PayPal",
            "paypal_name_text": "PayPal",
            "place_order_action": "Złóż zamówienie",
            "place_order_error": "Wystąpił błąd podczas składania zamówienia. Prosze skontaktuj się z nami."
        },
        "redeemable": {
            "applied_text": "Zastosowano",
            "apply_action": "Zastosuj",
            "apply_store_credit_after_action": "Wykorzystaj dodatkowe złotówki",
            "apply_store_credit_before_action": "Zastosuj",
            "code_invalid_error": "Karta podarunkowa lub kod zniżkowy jest nieważny.",
            "code_label": "Karta podarunkowa lub kupon zniżkowy",
            "code_required_error": "Prosze wprowadzić kartę podarunkową lub kupon zniżkowy.",
            "coupon_text": "Kupon zniżkowy",
            "gift_certificate_remaining_text": "Pozostało",
            "gift_certificate_text": "Karta podarunkowa",
            "remove_action": "Usuń",
            "store_credit_available_text": "Twoje konto posiada {storeCredit} dodatkowych złotówek do wykorzystania",
            "toggle_action": "Kupon zniżkowy/promocyjny"
        },
        "remote": {
            "connection_error": "Połączenie ze zdalną kasą zostało odrzucona, proszę spróbować później.",
            "continue_with_text": "Lub kontynuuj",
            "payment_method_error": "There was an error retrieving your remote payment method. Please try again. Wystąpił błąd podczas otrzymywania zdalnej płatności. Proszę spróbować później.",
            "session_error": "Twoja sesja wygasła. Prosze zaloguj się ponownie.",
            "shipping_address_error": "Wystąpił brąd podczas przetwarzania Twojego adresu dostawy. Prosze spróbuj jeszcze raz.",
            "sign_out_action": "Wyloguj się z {providerName}",
            "sign_out_after_action": "aby zobaczyć pozostałe metody płatności",
            "sign_in_required_error": "Zalogowanie się jest niezbędne przed dokonaniem płatności.",
            "sign_out_before_action": ""
        },
        "shipping": {
            "cart_change_error": "Została wykryta aktualizacja produktów w koszyku, wycena Twojej dostawy została zaktualizowana. Wybierz sposób dostawy aby kontynuować.",
            "enter_shipping_address_text": "Prosze wprowadzić adres dostawy aby uzyskać jej wycenę.",
            "order_comment_label": "Komentarz do zamówienia",
            "save_shipping_address_error": "Wystąpił błąd podczas zapisywania adresu dostawy. Prosze spróbować ponownie.",
            "save_shipping_option_error": "Wystąpił błąd podczas zapisywania wyceny Twojej dostawy. Proszę spróbuj jeszcze raz.",
            "select_shipping_address_text": "Prosze wybrać adres dostawy w zamówieniu aby uzyskać dane do wyceny.",
            "shipping_address_heading": "Adres dostawy",
            "shipping_heading": "Dostawa",
            "shipping_method_label": "Forma dostawy",
            "shipping_option_expired_error": "Cena dostawy nie jest już aktyalna. Kliknij OK aby zaktualizować.",
            "shipping_option_expired_heading": "Cena Twojej dostawy została zaktualizowana.",
            "view_shipping_options_action": "Zobacz pozostałe opcje"
        },
        "social": {
            "share_action": "Udostępnij",
            "share_heading": "Pochwal się znajomym swoim zakupem.",
            "tweet_action": "Tweetuj"
        },
        "terms_and_conditions": {
            "agreement_required_error": "Proszę zaakceptuj regulamin",
            "agreement_text": "Tak, akcepyuję regulamin sklepu.",
            "agreement_with_link_text": "Tak, zgadzam się z warunkami <a href=\"{url}\" target=\"_blank\">regulaminu</a>",
            "terms_and_conditions_heading": "Regulamin"
        },
        "order_confirmation": {
            "order_number_text": "Numer Twojego zamówienia to <strong>{orderNumber}</strong>",
            "order_pending_review_text": "Twoje zamówienie zostało złożone i oczekuje na zaksięgowanie płatności. Po otrzymaniu płatności rozpoczniemy prosces wysyłki.",
            "order_with_downloadable_digital_items_text": "Możesz pobrać swoje produkty poprzez kliknięcie w link na tej stronie, lub poprzez zalogowanie się na swoje konto. Link do pobrania otrzymasz także w emailu z potwierdzeniem zamówienia.",
            "order_with_support_number_text": "Wysyłamy do Ciebie e-mail z inormacjami dotyczącymi Twoich zakupów. Jeśli masz dodatkowe pytania napisz do nas <a ng-href=\"mailto:{supportEmail}?Subject=Order {orderNumber}\" target=\"_top\">{supportEmail}</a> lub zadzwoń na <a href=\"tel://{supportPhoneNumber}\">{supportPhoneNumber}</a>.",
            "order_without_downloadable_digital_items_text": "Gdy otrzymamy Twoją płatnośc prześlemy do Ciebie e-mail z jej potwierdzenienim.",
            "order_without_support_number_text": "Wyślemy do Ciebie e-mail zawierający inormacje o Twoim zamówieniu. Jeżeli masz dodatkowe pytania napisz do nas <a ng-href=\"mailto:{supportEmail}?Subject=Order {orderNumber}\" target=\"_top\">{supportEmail}</a>.",
            "thank_you_customer_heading": "Dziękujemy {name}!",
            "thank_you_heading": "Dziękujemy!"
        }
    }
}
```

can anybody suggest me right direction?

Comment: You should create a separate file for the language you want to translate to. Not edit the en.json file. https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/invoking-translation-keys#Syntax There is a super helpful video at the bottom of the page that walks through making the translation file and how to reference it.

Comment: @T.J. Thanks for the reply but I hope so you know well that bigcommerce not allow editing the checkout page content. so we cannot add the defined variable in the separate file to the checkout page.

Comment: You are able to edit the checkout to enable internationalization.  The video I linked gave a detailed explanation on how to do this. https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/localizing-stores#checkout . This also gives steps on how to edit the checkout for localization

Comment: Thanks for T.j the problem has been solved but i don't know how theme support solve the problem